# Sorting unbound datagridview programmatically

Tags: vb.net

I need to sort the datagridview programmatically.  I googled a lot but nothing worked for me.

Datagridview is not bound to any datasource.  Data is being added manually.
My requirement is to sort it as when a 'Sort' button is pressed.

Can anyone suggest me code in vb.net?

Comment: What do you think it should be?  Show us the code that you think should work and tell us exactly what happened when you compiled/ran it.

Comment: sorting based on which column?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try like this

`DataGridView1.Columns(0)` -> Give which column you want to sort
`System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending` -> Give direction of ascending or decending

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As 
 System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        DataGridView1.Sort(DataGridView1.Columns(0), 
        System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending)

 End Sub
```

Comment: will this work for `Datetime()` column in datagridview?

Answer (score 0):

The code above works.  You can, of course, choose any valid column.  Here it is in C#, the only difference is the square braces []:
`gridview.Sort( gridview.Columns[0], System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending );`