# How can I call this public sub when I add to the datagridview?

Tags: vb.net, sorting, datagridview

```
    Public Sub DataGridView1_SortCompare(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewSortCompareEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.SortCompare
    If e.Column.Index <> 0 Then
        Return
    End If
    Try
        e.SortResult = If(CDec(e.CellValue1) < CDec(e.CellValue2), -1, 1)
        e.Handled = True
    Catch
    End Try
End Sub
```

I'm pretty new to VB.net and can't seem to figure out how to call this sub

I have tried 
Call DataGridView1_SortCompare() but I'm obviously missing some parameters.

Basically I have a form2 that adds info to the datagridview but then I need it sorted  on column("num") after it's been added. I thought that the following code would work, but it returns an error of check for null.

```
Form1.DataGridView1.Sort(DataGridView1.Columns("num"), System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending)
```

Any Ideas on how I could accomplish this?

Thanks

Comment: Never used SortCompare  but why not just create a method and sort it like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24838753/sorting-unbound-datagridview-programatically

Comment: Actually that's the same code that is returning the null error.

Comment: You are getting a null error when trying to sort the datagridview?

Comment: Only when I try this line of code _Form1.DataGridView1.Sort(DataGridView1.Columns("num"), System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending)_. The sub works but I don't know how to call it when the grid is updated or changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have a form2 that adds info to the datagridview but then I need it sorted on column("num") after it's been added. I thought that the following code would work, but it returns an error of check for null.

```
Form1.DataGridView1.Sort(DataGridView1.Columns("num"), System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending)
```

Ok, so the above statement is executing on `form2`.  I am guessing that `form2` also has a `DataGridView1` since the compiler did not have an issue with the above statement, but does not have a "num" column.  Even if it did have such a column, it would be the wrong column.

`DataGridView1.Columns("num")` will not error if the column does not exist.  Instead it returns `Nothing` (null).  You need to reference the `Columns` property of `DataGridView1` on `Form1`.

```
Form1.DataGridView1.Sort(Form1.DataGridView1.Columns("num"), System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending)
```

Comment: You are correct, I have a datagridview on form2 as well. Now that you point that out the solution makes perfect sense! Thanks for your help!

Comment: @StephenPutnam, I am not certain, but it appears that you are using VB's default form instance properties(i.e. you refer to the class Form1 by its Name).  If you are making use of this _feature_, I respectfully suggest that you stop doing so.  It may seem like a nice feature, but it will come back to bite you at some point (multi-threading in particular).  It is a feature that was added to make VB6 code upgrades easier, but is really out of place in the object oriented VB.Net world.  It is cleaner to pass an object reference to another for its use instead using of a _global_ variable.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I understand your question. If you just populated the datagridview then if you were to create a basic sort method you could call it after the datagridview is populated. I created a sample for show:

```
Public Class Form1

Public Shared Sub Sort()

    Form1.DataGridView1.Sort(Form1.DataGridView1.Columns("num"), System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending)

End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    dt.Columns.Add("ID")
    dt.Columns.Add("num")
    dt.Columns(0).AutoIncrement = True

    For value As Integer = 0 To 5
        Dim R As DataRow = dt.NewRow
        If value <> 2 Then
            R("num") = "Test" & value
            dt.Rows.Add(R)
        Else
            R("num") = ""
            dt.Rows.Add(R)
        End If
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt

    Next
    Sort()
End Sub
End Class
```