# How do I retrieve and sort database rows alphabetically from access?

Tags: database, vb.net, sorting, ms-access, gridview

I want to retrieve rows from the database and then sort them alphabetically using the 'FirstName' field, and then display the sorted data in a Grid View.

I know there may be an easier and more straightforward way to do this using the functions on the Grid view itself, But I want to apply bubble sort onto the rows of data and then display it on the Grid View that way. I have so far retrieved 'FirstName' from the database and stored the data in a list so I can sort the list in order, and then use it to display the rest of the data in correct order in the Grid View.

I don't know if this the correct way to do it. If it is how do I now display the sorted data in the grid view?

Thanks a lot.

```
Dim myconnection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection
            Dim builder As New OleDbConnectionStringBuilder With
                   {
                       .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0",   'declaring databas provider 
                       .DataSource = "C:\Users\Hamza\Documents\POS system1.accdb"  'provides location of the database file 
                   }
            Dim str = "SELECT FirstName FROM Customers"
            Using connection As New OleDbConnection(builder.ConnectionString),
                    cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, connection)
    
                connection.Open()
    
                Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
    
                Fistname.Add(dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("FirstName")))
    
                connection.Close()
            End Using
```

Comment: Have you tried using ORDER BY clause in SQL statement?

Comment: I'm trying to sort the data using the bubble sort algorithm.

Comment: Review http://vb.net-informations.com/datagridview/vb.net_datagridview_sort.htm

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sorting unbound datagridview programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24838753/sorting-unbound-datagridview-programmatically)

Comment: See below, you don't specify if this is web based, or desktop winforms. The control GridView is for web, and DataGridView is for desktop. But you tagged this GridView. so, I posted both a web based version, and a desktop winforms version of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Ok first up. Obviously, we would not type the connection information over and over in code. What happens when you need to change which database.

so, go project->"my project name" properties.

Now, go to settings. and use the connection string builder to create a connection settings. And you can put in this page other handy settings - maybe company name (string), or even say a tax rate number or whatever.

So you see this:
[image]

When you click on connection builder above, you of course now get these dialogs:

[image]

Select change - and then choose Access

[image]

And now we have this - browse to access file:

[image]

Ok, we do the above, since now we have ONE PLACE for the connection.

And we also save a keyboard in which we do NOT type in the conneciton string in our code. As noted, you can add all kinds of handy application settings in above.

Ok, so we created our connection.

Now, the next part. We want to allow sorting of our data. Say FirstName, Hotel Name, or City.

So, we drop into our page, a Radio button list, and then say a gridview.

We have this for Radio button:

[image]

Edit items, lets type in the sort choices for the user.

[image]

Note for the first option First name - we also set selected = true (our default sort)

And now bring up property sheet for Radio button list - set to horizonal

[image]

ALSO set autopostback = true in above radio button list.

Ok, now drag + drop in that Grid view below the Radio button list

We have this markup so far:

```
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" CellSpacing="15" AutoPostBack="True">
            <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="FirstName">By First Name</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="HotelName">by Hotel Name</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="City">by City</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:RadioButtonList>

        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CssClass="table" Width="30%">
        </asp:GridView>
```

I also set the cell spacing for radio button list.

I really did not have to type in any of that markup, but you should have the above so far.

Now, right click - view code, and lets wire this up:

top of code we need:

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.OleDb
```

and our code now looks like:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then

        LoadGrid()

    End If

End Sub

Sub LoadGrid()

    Using conn As New OleDbConnection(My.Settings.AccessDB)
        Dim strSQL As String =
            "SELECT FirstName, LastName, City, HotelName, Description FROM tblHotels 
            ORDER BY " &
            RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem.Value

        Using cmdSQL As New OleDbCommand(strSQL, conn)

            conn.Open()
            Dim rstData As New DataTable
            rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
            GridView1.DataSource = rstData
            GridView1.DataBind()

        End Using
    End Using

End Sub
```

And now we see/have this:

[image]

Only part left is to add the event for when we click on Radiobutton list to change the sort.

So, property sheet for RB list, events, and then select on-change event

[image]

And we now have this code:

```
Protected Sub RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndexChanged

    LoadGrid()

End Sub
```

So, as a general rule, we simple can set/change/have any sql, and we can include the SQL in the sort

So,

```
 SELECT * from tblHotels ORDER BY HotelName.
```

And then just feed that to the grid as per above.

## Edit: This might be for desktop - desktop (winforms) below

It not clear if this is for desktop, but if desktop?

Then really much the same as per above.

We drop into a form a GroupBox (so only 1 radio button will select).

we then drop in a DataGridView  (NO such thing as GridView in desktop).

We now have this:

[image]

We can wire up a click event for the first radio button (use property sheet)

And then for the next two radio buttons use specify the SAME click event.

So, we now have this code:

```
Private Sub RadioGrid_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    LoadGrid()

End Sub

Sub LoadGrid()

    Using conn As New OleDbConnection(My.Settings.AccessDB)
        Dim strSQL As String =
            "SELECT FirstName, LastName, City, HotelName, Description FROM tblHotels "
        
        Dim strSortBy As String = ""

        if RadioButton1.Checked then strSortBy = "FirstName"
        if RadioButton2.Checked then strSortBy = "HotelName"
        If RadioButton3.Checked Then strSortBy = "City"

        If strSortBy <> "" Then
            strSQL &= " ORDER BY " & strSortBy
        End If


        Using cmdSQL As New OleDbCommand(strSQL, conn)

            conn.Open()
            Dim rstData As New DataTable
            rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
            DataGridView1.DataSource = rstData

        End Using
    End Using


End Sub

Private Sub RadioButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadioButton1.Click, RadioButton3.Click, RadioButton2.Click

    LoadGrid()

End Sub
```

And results are this:

[image]